# AttributeError when validating schema with marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a POST and PUT route with marshmallow schema and sqlalchemy template but when I do the PUT or POST request I get an error. This error is generated when I validate to verify that the received object corresponds to the schema.

- Model SQLAlchemy

```py
class EquipmentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "equipments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('equipment_id_seq'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    model = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, model, serial_number, brand, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.model = model
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        self.brand = brand

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<EquipmentModel('%d', '%s')>" % (self.id, self.brand)
```

- Schema Marshmallow

```py
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from marshmallow import fields

ma = Marshmallow()

class EquipmentSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    brand = fields.String(required=True)
    model = fields.String(required=True)
    serial_number = fields.String(required=True)
```

- Validation

```
schema = EquipmentSchema()
body = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
body, errors = schema.load(body)
```

- When I do this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__mapper__'
```

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that you need to give the schema the model in Meta like so:

```
class EquipmentSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    brand = fields.String(required=True)
    model = fields.String(required=True)
    serial_number = fields.String(required=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "brand", "model", "serial_number")
        model = EquipmentModel
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, could be marked as an answer.